# Rendering a page with data from two tables with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm making my first web dev project and I want to render a page that can access the content of two tables inside the same db, but I can't find how to do it in the documentation. I'm using PostgreSQL, express, node.js, and sequelize.

```
Promise
    .all(Marcas.findAll(), TiposAparelhos.findAll())
    .then((data) => {
        res.render('aparelhos/gerenciador', {
            marcas: data[0], tiposAparelhos: data[1]
        })
})
```

I already tried this method but it didn't work

Comment: You do you measn by `didn't work`? Empty result? Errors?

Comment: The console is telling me that there's a unhandled promise rejection, but I don't know how to handle it

Comment: Can you add `catch` to the chain and look at the error?

Comment: Yes and I found the issue. I have a a variable named 'message' in the page and I forgot to assign a value to it. I just added message: "" after tiposAparelhos: data[1] and now it works.  
It's a dumb mistake by me, thanks for your help